# How to get list of imported polymer-elements?

Tags: javascript, polymer

How to get full list of polymer-element's which was imported before?

Comment: Can you give more info on why you're looking to do this? This is generally a bad idea as it breaks modularization (your elements shouldn't care what other elements are present on the page, or whether another element was implemented with Polymer or x-tags or native code in the browser, or a framework that doesn't exist yet). If you want to look for a particular element or elements to see if it's registered, that should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Import de-duplication allows you to not have to worry about this in general.

you could also have X-Tags, raw custom elements, or any other kind.

Example:

```
var allElements = document.all;
var polymerElements = [];
for (var i = 0; i< allElements.length; i++){
  var tagName = allElements[i].localName;
  if(tagName && tagName.indexOf('polymer-') > -1){
    polymerElements.push(tagName);
  }
}
console.log(polymerElements);
```

Comment: ok. what about performance of brute-force page scanning when it contain 1000000 elements? :)

Comment: Then use this polymer patch: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zonito/mypolymer/master/polymer.js /https://github.com/zonito/mypolymer/blob/master/polymer.js 

To get list of imported polymer elements:
    <script>
      Polymer.polymerComponents()
    </script>

Comment: And where is the source code? :) this is a bad solution to patch current framework. If there is no way to do this - mean i thought in wrong way. Should exist another architecture to does this.

Comment: I understand, its not standard. But no harm till it fulfills your requirement. I don't think, they have it for now.